# I can't add the last post as featured

Tags: wordpress

I have the following query that shows me 1 post that has the featured tag, that works fine, but if I want to leave another featured, I have to deactivate the first one, what can I do so that only the last featured is added, without deactivating the previous? (they are activated with a check field)

```
<?php
global $post;

$array_terms    = [];
$term_destacado = 'destacado';
$data           = [
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $term_destacado,
];
array_push( $array_terms, $data );

$myposts = get_posts( [
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'post_type'      => 'podcast',
    'tax_query'      => ['relation' => 'AND', $array_terms],

] );
if ( $myposts ) {
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) :
        setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
```

Comment: You might not be able to. You need to deactivate it unless there is some other data that says that the newest one should be checked. You might be able to do `'order' => 'modified'`

Comment: where should i add that line?

Comment: Thanks,  it worked for me to overwrite the previous one

Comment: I'll add an answer, since this is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query to order by modified date, since the new post that you want featured will be the newest/most recent one that was saved.

You can add: `'order' => 'modified'` to your query.

Add it in the `$my_posts` array:

```
$myposts = get_posts( [
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'post_type'      => 'podcast',
    /* ADDED HERE */
    'order'          => 'modified',
    'tax_query'      => ['relation' => 'AND', $array_terms],

] );
```